# Abrir modal com JavaScript para selecionar certificado e enviar para o servidor

Tags: javascript, java, spring, nfe, certificado-digital

Quando entramos na página [eCAC - Centro Virtual de Atendimento](https://cav.receita.fazenda.gov.br/) e clicamos em Certificado Digital do lado direito da tela é aberto um modal para selecionar determinado certificado que configuramos no sistema (isso se houver certificado(s) no sistema configurados). Segue a imagem do modal com a descrição do modal apagada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como posso implementar um recurso parecido com esse em determinada aplicação do sistema utilizando JavaScript para carregar o certificado NF-e do cliente e utilizar com o intuito de enviar as notas fiscais para o Governo e efetuar outras operações com as mesmas. Ainda não descobri por onde começar e foram poucos os materiais encontrados.

Comment: Enviar o arquivo é até possível, porém não é assim que se valida o certificado. Primeiramente porque somente o tipo A1 seria possível ler e ele precisa ser **instalado no computador**, o que exige a digitação da senha. O do tipo A3 não tem como ler sem um leitor específico, pois ele é do tipo *inviolável*.

Comment: E este certificado precisa ser disponibilizado no servidor ou fica somente no lado do cliente?

Comment: Precisa ser instalado no sistema que for emitir a NF, ou seja, voce precisa passar seu certificado e digitar a sua senha. Todos os sistemas que vi que fazem o que voce quer fazer exigem que voce disponibilize seu certificado para o sistema emissor. É uma espécie de compartilhamento de seu certificado.

Comment: Algum exemplo de código que permita esse compartilhamento? O certificado já esta instalado corretamente na máquina, foi instalado um arquivo com a extensão .pfx

Comment: Como seu sistema é para Java, creio que este projeto possa lhe ajudar. https://github.com/wmixvideo/nfe

Comment: Já estou utilizando ele, a questão agora é, fazer igual o eCAC faz ou terei que armazenar o certificado do cliente em um diretório no servidor?

Comment: Vai precisar criar um formulário onde o cliente coloque o certificado (upload de arquivo) e a senha do certificado A1. Depois é só usar a classe para consumir o Webservice do Sefaz referente a unidade da federação correta. 
Entenda que esse modelo é diferente do que o eCac faz onde já lê o certificado diretamente do navegador que por sua vez lê do S.O. Para evitar fazer isso toda vez que for trabalhar com esse Certificado, pode-se armazenar no servidor as informações. No caso do A3 seria preciso um applet para se comunicar com o leitor TODA vez que for utilizar. Não dá pra armazenar.

Comment: E como fazer da forma que o eCac faz? No caso eu estou utilizando ASP.NET MVC, mas acredito que se a linguagem utilizada para fazer isso for web, como por exemplo o javascript, eu consigo implementar em ASP.NET também. Como então fazer a leitura do certificado através do navegador?

Comment: Ainda estou com essa dúvida amigo e não encontrei a solução até o momento

Comment: Giancarlo tudo bem? bom, estou tendo a mesma dúvida, conseguiu encontrar alguma solução?

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não, se encontrar posto uma resposta aqui (;

Comment: O processo que abre esse "modal" é uma negociação em tempo de conexão (camada de rede) chamado TSL Handshake, expliquei um pouco de como funciona, e como implementei no meu próprio sistema o fluxo com PHP(https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195838/7130) similar ao do certsign: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198803/7130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, depois de muito tempo, eu consegui encontrar uma solução,
no dia de hoje a Certisign possui uma API que faz a validação de certificados digitais.

Se não me engano um GET com javascript é bloqueado pelo CORS da aplicação deles,

```html
<form action=" https://autenticador.certisign.com.br/CertisignLogin/certificado/login?id={idDaChave}&nome={nomeDaChave}&retorno={urlDeRetorno}"
  method="get">
   <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Utilizando um form, quando vc for enviar, ele automaticamente solicitará a escolha do certificado, e abrirá o modal.

Nesta URL de retorno, ele te enviará um token, criptografado, caso seja autenticado, e você terá acesso aos dados, como por exemplo:

```js
CertificadoBean:
{
  emissor: Certisign Autoridade Certificadora TESTE,
  nome: "PROPRIETARIO DO CERTIFICADO DE TESTE",
  cpf: "001.002.003-44",
  cnpj: "",
  OAB: "",
  validade: "2015-05-27 20:59:59",
  emissao: "2014-05-27 21:00:00",
  email: "proprietario.teste@certisign.com.br",
  certificadoBase64: "MIIFmDCCBICgAwI...... BAQUFADCCARAx"
}
```

Caso tenha mais dúvidas, 
https://www.certisign.com.br/solucoes-corporativas/seguranca-e-gerenciamento/certisignlogin/desenvolvedores

Aqui em minha equipe, tivemos algumas dúvidas, então ligamos para eles, no telefone que está no site.
Nos atenderam super bem e responderam todas as nossas dúvidas.

Comment: Boa tarde conseguiu resolver isso? eu tentei fazer, abriu a tela para selecionar o certificado e cliquei, mas fica dando loop na página, sabe me dizer porque?