# Como configurar a ordem correta de certificados para solicitar certificados e-CPF e e-CNPJ do ICP-Brasil?

Tags: segurança, autenticação, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital, brasil

Para solicitar um certificado digital instalado na máquina Cliente de uma aplicação web e acessar a chave pública desse certificado digital no backend (node, php, go, etc) é necessário habilitar a opção "SSL/TSL Handshake" no servidor web, no caso de uma linguagem interpretada como o PHP é necessário exportar essa informação via variável de ambiente [permitindo o acesso, após autorizado e selecionado, pela linguagem que está por trás da aplicação web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/194946/7130).

Porém, apenas certificados que estão na lista de Autoridades Certificadoras(CA) no "[CA bundle](https://suporte.webtuga.pt/Knowledgebase/Article/View/120/20/o-que-e-um-certificate-authority-ca-bundle)" são permitidos e listados no prompt da interface do navegador.

> O CA bundle, define a cadeia certificadora que é confiável para a autenticação neste site.

No caso do e-CPF e e-CNPJ, que são certificados digitais assinados pela cadeia certificadora da [ICP-Brasil](http://www.iti.gov.br/icp-brasil).

Eu usei [um script](https://gist.github.com/skarllot/9663935) para baixar e gerar o bundle com todos os certificados disponibilizados publicamente no site oficial, porém não obtive sucesso ao implementar o arquivo gerado no meu webserver pois a ordem gerada por esse script é aleatória, e para solicitar corretamente é necessária uma ordem específica respeitando uma certa hierarquia que não sei como definir por falta de documentação e informação em manuais técnicos.

Como este script baixa todos os certificados, ainda está permitindo a inclusão de certificados do tipo NF-e e da OAB, o que não é o foco da pergunta.

O resultado esperado é algo parecido com esse:

[image: Exemplo do prompt]

Tentar todas as combinações não seria uma opção no momento pois são mais de 133 certificados do diretório principal (disponível aqui para quem precisar baixar: http://www.iti.gov.br/icp-brasil/repositorio/144-icp-brasil/repositorio/3886-repositorio-de-certificados-arquivo-unico-compactado).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Após algumas pesquisas em diversos sites, obtive o resultado esperado.

Para completar o fluxo do SSL Handshake, o servidor precisa dizer quais certificados são aceitos, desta forma o navegador irá exibir o prompt de seleção com apenas certificados possivelmente válidos para completar essa requisição, conforme o diagrama abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta forma, É necessário adicionar apenas os certificados "Raiz" nesse "bundle" de CAs. Esse arquivo combinado deve respeitar à  [RFC 4346](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.4.2) usando os delimitadores de forma correta para que o arquivo seja lido corretamente pelo servidor web.

A ordem que está funcionando comigo é a seguinte:

1. Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5 (NF-e/e-CPF/e-CNPJ v5)
2. Raiz Brasileira V2 (e-CPF/e-CNPJ v2)

Desta forma:

```
CA do HTTPS do site 
==========
(...)
= CA ICP Brasil =
(NF-e/e-CPF/e-CNPJ v5)Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5
==========
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----



(e-CPF/e-CNPJ v2) Raiz Brasileira V2
===========================================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Estas 2 atendem os certificados mais novos.
É possível baixá-las no site oficial:

http://www.iti.gov.br/icp-brasil/certificados/188-atualizacao/4530-ac-raiz

Comment: esse bundle que vc cita acima, deve ser configurado em qual parâmetro do apache?

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr  Você deve combinar os certificados na configuração do seu apache nessa pergunta eu dei mais detalhes de como isso funciona: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/194946/7130 Aqui tem um exemplo com apache também:
https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho como tu faz pra enviar pro navegador que vc precisa de um certificado? eu não entendi ainda. ele funciona pra A3 do e-cpf/e-cnpj?

Comment: @HagaHood respondi nessa pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198803/7130

Basicamente eu obtenho por um subdomínio configurado com o parâmetro de SSL/TLS Handshake (pois não dá para configurar apenas para um alias)  e transfiro via post com uma criptografia própria.

Comment: Obrigado @LeonanCarvalho, me tirou de um grande sufoco! Usei os mesmos certs que tu listou, e funcionou legal!

Comment: @JhonnyMesquita fico contente em saber que meu problema ajudou tanta gente, a pesar do site ter marcado a pergunta como fora de foco, está ajudando muito "overflow" de devs do Brasil