# Como obter o número do CPF/CNPJ de um certificado digital do tipo e-CPF/e-CNPJ nos modelos A1 e A3?

Tags: ssl, certificado-digital, openssl, brasil

Eu estou desenvolvendo um método alternativo para login via certificado, sem precisar de java ou uma linguagem expecífica, apenas http e php para processar informações backend(mas que poderia ser manipulado por qualquer outra linguagem que processe http). Os métodos mais comuns que existem são o da [Certsign](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139462/certificado-digital-a3-e-cpf-como-acessar-as-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-javascript/194946#194946), porém elepossui uma baixa interoperabilidade limitando-se à linguagens como .NET e Java. Além disso este método depende do web-service deles para se obter os CPF do certificado, caso o sistema deles esteja fora não é possível altenticar o usuário.

Sabemos que é possível solicitar o [certificado através do SSL Handshake](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195053/qual-%C3%A9-a-ordem-correta-da-cadeia-de-certificados-da-icp-brasil-para-que-o-certif/197549#197549), que habilita o servidor web à abrir uma solicitar o certificado do cliente dentro de uma cadeia de certificados pré-selecionada, o que fará exatamente o que a Certsign faz.

Os dados que eu consigo extrair de um certificado NF-e são esses(obfuscado):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já fizemos a solicitação de um e-CPF e um e-CNOJ, a questão está, aonde dentro dos dados publicos do certificado estão as informações referente ao número do cpf ou cnpj?

Comment: _ Por favor, quem está negativando esta pergunta favor comentar o motivo e o que fazer para ser merecedor do teu digníssimo apoio. _

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após obter um certificado A1 e A3 válido (e não os de testes que foram usados para confecção da pergunta), foi possível identificar que no  campo `S_DN_CN` do certificado contém o nome e o número do documento.

No grupo de  `Distinguished Name (DN)`  no `Common Name(CN)` do certificado é possível visualizar uma String composta pelo Nome (e-CPF) ou Razão Social(e-CNPJ) seguido de  dois pontos ":"  e a sequência numérica do CPF ou do CNPJ cadastrado.

Por exemplo:

[No php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80568/certificado-digital-com-php/195838#195838) é possível obter através da chave **SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN**, exemplo:

```
<?php 

    list ($nome, $documento) = explode(":", $ssl["SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN"]);
?>
```

Após isso pode-se aplicar algorítimos de teste cpf e cnpj para identificar qual tipo de documento representa este certificado.

A descrição da composição do DN pode ser encontrado no item 
2.1.12. Composição do Distinguished Name (DN) do certificado e-CPF  e 3.1.12. Composição do Distinguished Name (DN) do certificado e-CNPJ 
da documentação https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/acsrf/LeiautedeCertificadosdaSRF.pdf

Comment: Por acaso está no item 2.1.12 da documentaçãoi que vc mesmo indicou (3.1.12 para CNPJ). E no 2.2.5 estão outros campos de documentos, cada um com seu respectivo OID.

Comment: Ainda, no mesmo manual, o terceiro campo "OU" indica se é e-CPF ou e-CNPJ, e o respectivo tipo

Comment: Obrigado, acabou passando despercebido!

Comment: Complementando, esta resposta é válida para eCPF e eCNPJ (e vários outros tipos de certificado), mas não serve para todos os certificados ICP-Brasil (sei que a pergunta é só sobre eCPF/eCNPJ, é só para complementar mesmo). Existem, por exemplo, certificados OAB e AC-JUS que possuem o número de registro no DN (ou não possuem número algum), além de outros tipos que podem ter outros dados. Nestes casos, o mais garantido é buscar o CPF/CNPJ na extensão Subject Alternative Name (seção 2.2.5 do documento que vc indicou). E para saber se é A1 ou A3: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/418059/112052

Answer (score 0):

utilizei as seguintes libs e resolvi com o codigo abaixo (to considerando que o p7b tá base64-encoded, mas se o seu p7b não tiver, podem tirar a linha do decode):

[image: bibiliotecas utilizadas]

```
       File f = new File("c:/temp/teste.p7b");

       byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
       in.readFully(buffer);
       in.close();

       byte[] arquivo = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.decode(buffer);

       CMSSignedData signature = new CMSSignedData(arquivo);
       Store cs = signature.getCertificates();
       SignerInformationStore signers = signature.getSignerInfos();
       Collection c = signers.getSigners();
       Iterator it = c.iterator();

       byte[] data = null;

       Collection certCollection = cs.getMatches(null);
       Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();

        while(certIt.hasNext()) {

            X509CertificateHolder cert = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();

            CMSProcessable sc = signature.getSignedContent();
            data = (byte[]) sc.getContent();

            X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(cert);

            if (certificate.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.17") != null) {
                System.out.println(new String(certificate.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.17"), "UTF-8"));
                System.out.println(certificate);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Olá Anderson seja bem-vindo ao SOpt !
Bacana seu interesse em ajudar e tenho certeza que sua resposta até possa ajudar outras pessoas, mas a pergunta vai muito além do titulo o conteúdo descrito por quem perguntou contém informações úteis que lhe guiarão a dar uma resposta mais coesa. No caso, a pergunta se referia a um método que não usasse java :)

Comment: entendi, foi a pressa em ajudar. se vc n conseguir, podera expor o java como um webservice e consumi-lo no seu php. abs.

Comment: Da uma olhadinha nessa solução: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195838/7130