# Como identificar se o certificado é A1 ou A3?

Tags: java, certificado-digital

Existe uma forma segura de identificar, a partir de um objeto `X509Certificate`, se o certificado é A1 ou A3?

Estou usando a função abaixo, mas muito sujeita a falhas:

```
// Certificados podem ter descrições diferentes. Foram encontrados os casos abaixo
// "OU=Assinatura Tipo A3"
// "OU=RFB e-CPF A3"
private static boolean isA3(X509Certificate cert) {
    final String name = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
    final String[] issueValues = name.split(",");
    for (String value : issueValues) {
        final String[] field = value.split("=");
        if (field[0].equals("OU"))
            if (field[1].endsWith("A3"))
                return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os certificados ICP-Brasil possuem a extensão [Certificate Policies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.4), segundo consta no respectivo [documento da Receita Federal](https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/acsrf/LeiautedeCertificadosdaSRF.pdf) (veja a seção 1.2.4):

> o campo policyIdentifier contém o OID da Política de Certificação (PC) que a AC
> titular do certificado implementa;

Sendo assim, basta ler esta extensão e ver o valor que tem lá:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.x509.extension.X509ExtensionUtil;

X509Certificate cert = ...
// obter a extensão CertificatePolicies
byte[] value = cert.getExtensionValue(X509Extension.certificatePolicies.getId());
DERSequence seq = (DERSequence) X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(value);
DERObjectIdentifier oid = (DERObjectIdentifier) ((DERSequence) seq.getObjectAt(0)).getObjectAt(0);
System.out.println(oid.getId());
if (oid.getId().startsWith("2.16.76.1.2.3.")) {
    // A3
} else if (oid.getId().startsWith("2.16.76.1.2.1.")) {
    // A1
}
```

Eu usei a biblioteca [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) para ler o valor da extensão, pois interpretar os bytes manualmente é querer muito reinventar a roda. Para o código acima, usei a versão 1.46.

Enfim, o valor desta extensão é bem definido entre as AC's, e o importante é que todos possuem os mesmos dígitos iniciais, variando apenas o último dígito, que indica a AC específica. Alguns exemplos:

Serasa

- A3: 2.16.76.1.2.3.10
- A1: 2.16.76.1.2.1.13

Certisign:

- A3: 2.16.76.1.2.3.6
- A1: 2.16.76.1.2.1.12

Estes valores podem ser consultados nas respectivas Políticas de Certificado de cada AC:

- Serasa [A3](https://serasa.certificadodigital.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/PC_A3_AC_Serasa_RFB.pdf) e [A1](https://serasa.certificadodigital.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/PC_A1_AC_Serasa_RFB.pdf) (os valores são indicados na seção 1.2.2, embora o documento da Serasa A3 esteja com o número errado (tem um "2" a mais no início)
- Certisign [A3](http://icp-brasil.certisign.com.br/repositorio/pc/AC_Certisign_RFB/PC_AC_CERTISIGN_RFB_A3_V7.1.pdf) e [A1](http://icp-brasil.certisign.com.br/repositorio/pc/AC_Certisign_RFB/PC_AC_CERTISIGN_RFB_A1_V7.1.pdf), na seção 1.2

De qualquer forma, repare que para A3, ambos começam com `2.16.76.1.2.3` e somente o último dígito varia, pois ele indica a respectiva AC. Você pode consultar o valor `2.16.76.1.2.3` [aqui](http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=2.16.76.1.2.3&action=display), e veja que ele corresponde a "Certificate policy A3" (e veja também que todos os OID's que começam com `2.16.76.1` é porque estão abaixo da ICP-Brasil).

Já se você consultar `2.16.76.1.2.3.10`, verá que corresponde a um [A3 da Serasa-RFB](http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=2.16.76.1.2.3.10&action=display), enquanto `2.16.76.1.2.3.6` corresponde a um [A3 da Certisign-RFB](http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=2.16.76.1.2.3.6&action=display). De qualquer forma, todos que começam com `2.16.76.1.2.3.` são A3.

A mesma lógica vale para A1, basta começar com `2.16.76.1.2.1.`.

Repare que o ponto no final da string é importante, pois existem OID's como [`2.16.76.1.2.303`](http://oid-info.com/get/2.16.76.1.2.303) e [`2.16.76.1.2.101`](http://oid-info.com/get/2.16.76.1.2.101), então é importante que a comparação seja `startsWith("2.16.76.1.2.1.")` (se o último ponto for removido, você pode erroneamente considerar que `2.16.76.1.2.101` é um A1, por exemplo).

---

Se quiser saber a URL da respectiva Política de Certificado (o endereço do documento), ela também fica na mesma extensão - no exemplo acima, basta percorrer a sequência `seq`, ou imprimi-la diretamente, para ver esta URL. O código não é lá muito bonito:

```
DERSequence subSeq = (DERSequence) ((DERSequence) seq.getObjectAt(0)).getObjectAt(1);
DEREncodable url = ((DERSequence) subSeq.getObjectAt(0)).getObjectAt(1);
System.out.println(url.toString());
```

Se quiser, também pode fazer vários loops pela `DERSequence` (usando `size()` para saber o tamanho e `getObjectAt` para obter o respectivo objeto). Mas como esta estrutura é uma sequência dentro de outra dentro de outra, é bem "chatinho" de percorrê-la.

---

Em versões anteriores do Bouncy Castle era possível usar a classe `CertificatePolicies`, mas seus métodos estão *deprecated* (apesar de ainda funcionarem):

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.CertificatePolicies;

byte[] value = cert.getExtensionValue(X509Extension.certificatePolicies.getId());
CertificatePolicies cp = CertificatePolicies.getInstance(X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(value));
String policy = cp.getPolicy(0);
if (policy.startsWith("2.16.76.1.2.3.")) {
    // A3
} else if (policy.startsWith("2.16.76.1.2.1.")) {
    // A1
}
```

Comment: Não conhecia a Bouncy Castle, ajudou muito. Inclusive a utilizei para ler o CPF ou CNPJ do certificado, de forma muito mais amigável do que a implementação anterior sem ela.