# PHP com certificado do tipo A1

Tags: php, certificado-digital

Estou com a seguinte dúvida: comprei o certificado do tipo A1 para emitir notas fiscais eletronicas na prefeitura aqui de Florianopolis. Já integrei todo o meu sistema com a API da Prefeitura e a forma de gerar a NFe é bem simples: eu realizo um POST contendo um XML e pronto, a Prefeitura gerará a NFe.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: no final do arquivo XML há várias linhas que preciso preencher no formato abaixo. Como que eu gero essas linhas usando PHP e o certificado do tipo A1? Eu procurei bastante na internet e não descobri como que gero essa parte final do arquivo XML.

Por exemplo, no final do arquivo XML eu tenho que preencher um campo assim:

```
<ds:Reference Id="RefElement-3.496850484729869E7" URI="">
```

Como que eu defino o valor de RefElement?

Em outra parte do XML eu preciso preencher essa linha:

```
<ds:DigestValue>KsPAoHg2H0y/wSrrOGRihebcE/g=</ds:DigestValue>
```

Como que gero esse valor a partir do meu certificado digital A1?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse projeto talves ajude: https://github.com/nfephp-org/sped-nfe

Procure pelos métodos de "assinatura"  de arquivo.

Comment: obrigado amigo. Eu dei uma olhada nos metodos mas é muito confuso, tem muitos termos tecnicos ate mesmo nos comentarios!

Comment: Entendi, mas nessa linha de certificação não tem coisas muito simples não, são tópicos avançados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu utilizo a API NFePHP para realizar a emissão de notas fiscais, porém nunca desenvolvi uma nota de serviço, que é esta que utiliza os WebServices das Prefeituras.

segue o link do projeto da uma olhadinha lá.
https://github.com/nfephp-org

e caso fique com duvida existe um grupo no google sobre está ferramenta, o pessoal sempre ajuda bastante,
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nfephp

no youtube tem um video que explica como utilizar a ferramenta, me ajudou muito quando comecei (é um pouco longo mas vale a pena).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1rByVX1_FY

Espero que te ajude;

Comment: origado amigo o problema é que eu só preciso autenticar a nota, ou seja, gerar a assinatura eletronica dela e no nfephp fica muito confuso pois ele faz muito coisa!