# Certificados A3 e WEB

Tags: aplicação-web, certificado-digital

Olá, sei que possui algumas perguntas relacionadas ao tema, mas não consegui tirar nenhuma conclusão (pelo menos das que eu li), enfim é possível aplicar certificados digitais A3 (para autenticação e/ou assinatura) em aplicações WEB?

Li algumas respostas onde usuários dizem que é possível utilizar A3 em uma aplicação Web desde que tenha uma aplicação instalada no Usuário, se isso é viável alguém possui algum material sobre?

Comment: Sim, é possível. O que o usuário precisa instalar na máquina dele são os drivers para que o sistema reconheça a leitora do cartão/token. Do lado do servidor, basta configurá-lo para pedir o certificado do usuário na autenticação (e cada um é configurado de um jeito, procure na respectiva documentação). Se tudo estiver configurado, o browser faz o meio de campo, pedindo o certificado quando o site requisitar.

Comment: @hkotsubo o problema com esta metodologia é a limitação quando se usa o browser como intermediário, tanto para problemas de usabilidade ou para falta de funcionalidades mesmo, pelo menos foi isso que esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80568/certificado-digital-com-php). deu a entender

Comment: Mas se vai fazer um sistema web, tem que usar o browser (a menos que vc faça um aplicativo desktop que acesse a internet, mas aí esse aplicativo terá que lidar com as APIs do sistema operacional para ler o certificado (que é algo que o browser já faz, mesmo com todos os problemas citados). Não tem muito pra onde fugir, é problemático, tem problemas de usabilidade, mas ninguém conseguiu achar uma solução melhor

Comment: @hkotsubo o que algumas aplicações estão fazendo é utilizando um software instalado no computador do  usuário e uma extensão do navegador para gerenciar os certificados, assim o problema do suporte nativo dos navegadores é contornado.